# Found unexpected losses or metrics that do not correspond to any Model output

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, valueerror

I've three columns, namely 'student_star', 'student_difficult', and 'comments', in my dataset. I need to train the model on comments based on it predict 2 values of 'student_star' and 'student_difficult' through a single model.

```
# Create the GRU model
model = keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Embedding(num_words, embedding_dim, weights=[embedding_matrix], input_length=max_length, trainable=False))
model.add(keras.layers.GRU(128, return_sequences=True))
model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(keras.layers.GRU(64))
model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'))

# Output layer for 'student_star' and 'student_difficult'
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(6, activation='softmax', name='student_star'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='softmax', name='student_difficult'))

# Compile the model with a different optimizer
optimizer = keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=0.001)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Print the model summary
model.summary()
```

Above is the model that I trained on below dataset:

```
# Drop rows with null values in 'comments' column
data_frame.dropna(subset=['comments'], inplace=True)

# Select only the 'student_star' and 'comments' columns
data_frame = data_frame[['student_star', 'student_difficult', 'comments']]
```

When I try to fit the model using below code it throws me an error:

```
# Train the model on the training data
model.fit(X_train_pad, {'student_star': y_train['student_star'], 'student_difficult': y_train['student_difficult']}, 
          epochs=10, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.1)

# Evaluate the model on the test data
model.evaluate(X_test_pad, {'student_star': y_test['student_star'], 'student_difficult': y_test['student_difficult']})
```

I get:

```
ValueError: Found unexpected losses or metrics that do not correspond to any Model 
output: dict_keys(['student_star']). Valid mode output names: ['student_difficult']. 
Received struct is: {'student_star': }.
```

Comment: You cannot do a multi-output model with the Sequental API, only with the Functional API